# Processing lists of list in Python

Tags: python, list

Have been thinking and attempting with no results how to convert a list of lists into multiple lists.

For instance, the following lists of list:

```
['RZ', ['backho'], ['forest', 'arb']]
```

Should be converted to `n-lists` depending in the maximum length of the elements, so this results in two lists because of length of third element:

```
['RZ', 'backho', 'forest']
['RZ', 'backho', 'arb']
```

Each element in the list of lists represents the possibilities to be chosen for the element.

Comment: Do you mean the result should be a cartesian product?

Comment: @schwobaseggl please reopen, this question is not as simple as flattening.

Comment: Would `import itertools; [list(sublist) for sublist in itertools.product(*input)]` do what you want?

Comment: @Bjartr No, it does not, because `RZ` is not inside a `list`. Otherwise, it would.

Comment: @JuanPerez Could you perhaps explain a bit more what is the format of the input list? It looks like `'RZ'` and `['backho']` are treated equally. What should happen for e.g. `[0, [1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

lst = ['RZ', ['backho'], ['forest', 'arb']]
res = [list(p) for p in product([lst[0]], *lst[1:])]

print(res) # [['RZ', 'backho', 'forest'], ['RZ', 'backho', 'arb']]
```

Comment: or: `res = [list(p) for p in product(*[x if isinstance(x, list) else list(x) for x in lst])]` so that the simple `str` could be anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
for el in itertools.product(*['RZ', ['backho'], ['forest', 'arb']]):
    print(list(el))
```

and gives:

```
['R', 'backho', 'forest']
['R', 'backho', 'arb']
['Z', 'backho', 'forest']
['Z', 'backho', 'arb']
```

or if you want a list of list:

```
[list(el) for el in itertools.product(*['RZ', ['backho'], ['forest', 'arb']])]
```